# Does a Redirect in HTACCESS count as a Google Analytics hit?

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-302

I got tried of so many attempts to find WordPress on my web site which does not even have WordPress so I did a Redirect offsite.

Shortly after doing this my Google Analytics bounce rate went up at the exact same time.

Is this just coincidence?

RedirectMatch 302 /wp-login.php(.*) http://www.someotherdomain.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem is your htaccess code.**

If i follow you properly, you are noticing that people (bots) are visiting pages that do not exist on your site. I can show you the correct notation for your solution, by the way why not redirect to wordpress themselves :) . You also have the choice of redirecting permanently, i would do that instead as it shows visitors the page doesn't exist - you can use '301' (permanent) or '302' (temporary). You can also use "Redirect" for single pages or "RedirectMatch" which uses regex for more multipage re-directs, for your solution either can work, i show both below:

Here are your 2 "Redirect" options:

```
# Permanent Wordpress bot fix
Redirect 301 /wp-login.php https://wordpress.com/
```

OR

```
# Temporary Wordpress bot fix
Redirect 302 /wp-login.php https://wordpress.com/
```

Here are your 2 "RedirectMatch" options:

```
# Permanent Wordpress bot fix
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wp-login\.php$ https://wordpress.com/
```

OR

```
# Temporary Wordpress bot fix
RedirectMatch 302 ^/wp-login\.php$ https://wordpress.com/
```

The code that caused your trouble is **(.*)**, this is used in site-wide redirects, usually like this:

```
# Redirect ALL pages to home page
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://www.sitetwo.com
```

OR

```
# Redirect ALL pages, like for like
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://www.sitetwo.com/$1
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks Mark - I changed it RedirectMatch 301 ^/wp-login\.php$ https://wordpress.com/ - now comes the question this should be redirected before taking a page hit on my Analytics?

Comment: Yes, once the correct htaccess code is implemented google analytics will no longer track these hits as their tracking is done when the page renders... and the page doesn't render when a redirect is in place (so you had the right idea :) ). No more 404's for /wp-login.php in your reports!

Comment: Hey, why not test it yourself... when you go to www.yoursite.com/wp-login.php you should arrive at wordpress's site instead :)